# SSH log in for sagemath cloud project

Tags: ssh, sage

I am trying log in to one of my projects at sagemath cloud using SSH (I am using OS X 10.10.1) after adding the local copy of the public key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) to the authorized_keys file in the .ssh subdirectory of the project on the remote host, which is `162.222.176.40`:

```
$ ssh <project id>@162.222.176.40
The authenticity of host '162.222.176.40 (162.222.176.40)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 3a:40:8e:77:88:7e:f8:68:0c:28:4a:32:f8:4a:4a:25.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

Is this as expected?  I did check ~/.ssh/known_hosts and this host does not appear.  I am guessing it will be added once I log in for the first time.

Comment: ssh is complaining about the remote host's host key, not your personal key. What happens after the "RSA key fingerprint" line?

Comment: Thanks, it asks me whether I want to continue connecting, which I don't.  I asked William Stein, creator of Sage and the sagemath cloud, but he said he could not work out why either.

Will this hack work - adding the host to ~/.ssh/known_hosts and then trying to ssh?

Comment: Hi -- I definitely misunderstood your question.  I agree with Alex Ryan's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal to see a message like that once upon first connecting to a server. If it asks if it's ok to continue connecting, just say "yes". That public key will then be added to your local `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file (associated with that IP address or domain).

There's only a problem if you see this message every time you connect to a server. In that case, the problem might be that the given key is already in your local computer's `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file, but is associated there with a different IP address or domain. Try removing that line of the file, or just clearing that file completely.